# ReactJS: passing function to child component results in TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass a callback function from parent->child, but when the child component is rendered I get the error: `TypeError: this.props.setCurrentWindow is not a function`.

Parent component where I am trying to pass the function `setCurrentWindow`

```
class Parent extends Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.setCurrentWindow = this.setCurrentWindow.bind(this);
}

setCurrentWindow(){
  console.log("called")
}

render(){
  return(
      <Child
        setCurrentWindow={this.setCurrentWindow}
      />)}
    }
```

child component where I am trying to call `setCurrentWindow`

```
class Child extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }


  render(){
    return(
        <div 
          onClick={()=>{this.props.setCurrentWindow()}}>
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
    )}
  }
```

Why is `setCurrentWindow` not being recognized as a function here?

Comment: Perhaps you meant `{this.props.setCurrentWindow}` instead of `{this.props.setCurrentWindow()}`.

Comment: when I do that I get a compile error: `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression`

Comment: `onClick={this.props.setCurrentWindow}>`

Comment: If you update the code, you should explain that its not the same code giving you the error in question. Its very confusing to have to look through the questions edit history to see whats actually causing the error..

Comment: Ah that seems to work! I realize the error was in wrapping it in an anonymous function. In my full code I have multiple functions that are called on this onClick event, is there a way to call this within an anonymous arrow function ()=>{} , such that `onClick={()=>{this.props.setCurrentWindow(); this.setState({...}); this.myLocalFunction()}}`?

Comment: Why do you prefer to use the inline function? Its technically less performant and adds complexity to the JSX. But yes you can do that all inline

Comment: @BrianThompson my apologies with the edit, that was my mistake when copying the code over. My error was still the same however. Is there an easier way to do this as not an inline function?

Comment: @MuratYıldız I tried it and helped me discover what was really going on (see my answer to this thread). A very silly error that took up the better half of my day... thanks for the responses all

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A stupid answer but the final solution here is that not all instances of my child components were being passed this.setCurrentWindow hence the undefined error. Durrr! Thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 1):

Please check this example where I only found the difference is to have child element like `<div><h1>Hello</h1></div>` that was not in your code. other than this everything is working fine. When I click on the div, it writes **called** in `console`

```
export default class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.setCurrentWindow = this.setCurrentWindow.bind(this);
    }

    setCurrentWindow() {
        console.log("called")
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Child
                setCurrentWindow={this.setCurrentWindow}
            >
                <div>
                    <h1>Hello</h1>
                </div>
                </Child>
            )
    }
}

class Child extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={() => {
                this.props.setCurrentWindow()
            }}>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

***parent.jsx:***

```
class Parent extends Component {
  // code omitted for brevity

  handleSetWindow = () => {
    //
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child onSetWindow={this.handleSetWindow}
          />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

***child.jsx:***

```
class Child extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.onSetWindow()} >
          Set
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: No explanation as to what your code does different from the problem code? A code block and "try this" is generally not viewed as a quality answer.